# Tamanho e posição do div

Tags: html, css

Olá a todos eu estou a tentar por uma `div` ao lado de outra `div` como podem ver em baixo, eu não tenho a certeza do que estou a fazer mal está aqui o código:

```css
.div {
    background-color: #cecece; 
    margin-right: 700px; 
    padding-bottom: 424px;
    border: inset
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>C#</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="div">
   
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #000; margin-left: 400px; padding-bottom: 424px">
   w
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

O código não está a executar muito bem neste post por isso se for preciso veja o resultado nesta [página](http://liveweave.com/) tem de copiar o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `divs` por default têm display `block`, isto quer dizer que o elemento `div` vai ser colocado por baixo do elemento anterior:

EX:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Para remediar isso pode colocar um `float:left`:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Pode também colocar `display:inline-block`, mas note que por default este vai colocar uma `margin` entre os elementos (não percebo porquê, mas acontece) que pode ser retirada se colocar `font-size:0` no pai. Neste ultimo exemplo, pode ver isso se retirar `font-size:0` da `#caixa_pai`

```css
#caixa_pai {
  font-size:0;
}
.caixa_filho {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa_pai">
  <div class="caixa_filho" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="caixa_filho" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda é que durante o tempo de espera a unica solução que encontrei foi esta `.Block {background-color: #cecece; margin-left: 300px; margin-top: -430;padding-bottom: 424px;border: inset; margin-right: 600px;}` funcionava mas era má

Comment: Hehe isso não deve ser bom :P . Obgado, ainda bem que resolveu @Pekira

Comment: Eu estava aqui continuando a programar e eu gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de por uma textbox num div sem o div começar a alterar o tamanho <!-- language: lang-js -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>C#</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--DivCode-->
  <div class="code">
    <textarea rows="10" readonly="readonly" placeholder="">
  
    </textarea>
    </div>
   <!--DivBlock-->
  <div class="block" style="">
 
  </div>
   <!--DivScript-->
  <div class="script">

  </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: pois eu não faço a minima ideia como por isto como tu posseste

Comment: Pode sempre colocar um comprimento fixo na div: ex: `width:200px;` e a textbox: `display:block;width:100%;`. Não testei mas tenho quase a certeza que resulta @Pekira

Comment: Ok vou já tentar

Comment: Tem aqui um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/g5of2np2/1/

Comment: esta parte da textbox ponho css ou html?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43506/discussion-between-miguel-and-pekira).